# Setting Trusted Packages (ActiveMQ)

Tags: java, tomcat, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to send receive ActiveMQ messages. But I see the messages come back with this message in them.

```
JMSException in onMessage(): javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class com.logicalprovisioning.common.gtc.shared.GTCMessage! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.
```

So I read the link in the message. And I tried to follow the instructions. Although I must say its not very well written on where to put the configuration.

So what I did was:
1. I edited the ACTIVEMQ_OPTS line in activemq.bat file in the bin folder to

```
if "%ACTIVEMQ_OPTS%" == "" set ACTIVEMQ_OPTS=-Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config="%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%\login.config" -Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=com.logicalprovisioning.common.gtc.shared.GTCMessage
```

It didn't work.

2. I added the above line in the activemq.bat of the win64 folder as well. It didn't work.
3. I modified my subscriber object creation to add the Trusted Packages. Like:

   ```
   String providerEndpoints = "tcp://" + host + ":" + port + "?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=7200000";

   // Set the trusted packages/classes to move back and forth on the ActiveMQ JMS service.
   ArrayList<String> trustedClasses = new ArrayList<String>();

   trustedClasses.add("com.logicalprovisioning.common.gtc.shared.GTCMessage");

   // Obtain the factory
   ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();

   activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(providerEndpoints);

   // Add the trusted packages/classes to the ActiveMQ consumer.
   activeMQConnectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(trustedClasses);

   //Create the connection
   setConnection(activeMQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection());
   getConnection().setClientID(this.getName());

   // Make a session
   setSession(getConnection().createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE));

   getSession().createQueue(jmsDestination);

   // Create the destination
   Destination destination = getSession().createQueue(jmsDestination);

   String selector = "JMSCorrelationID = '" + getActionRequest().getOriginId() + "_" + getActionRequest().getRequestId() + "'" ;

   setConsumer(getSession().createConsumer(destination, selector));
   getConsumer().setMessageListener(new DefaultMessageListener(this));

   // Start ...
   gtcMessages = new GTCMessageQueue<GTCMessage>();  // We'll need a message store now
   getConnection().start();
   ```

And I added something similar in my producer as well for good measure:

```
    Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
        Context environmentContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");

        String queueConnectionFactoryNameLookup = PalInit.getProperty("jms.queue.connection.factory");

        // Set the trusted packages/classes to move back and forth on the ActiveMQ JMS service.
        ArrayList<String> trustedClasses = new ArrayList<String>();

        trustedClasses.add("com.logicalprovisioning.common.gtc.shared.GTCMessage");

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = (ActiveMQConnectionFactory) environmentContext.lookup(queueConnectionFactoryNameLookup);

        activeMQConnectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(trustedClasses);
        // Create connection
        QueueConnection queueConnection = activeMQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
        queueConnection.start();

        // Create session and producer
        setSession(queueConnection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE));

        String queueName = PalInit.getProperty("jms.destination");
        Queue jmsQueue = getSession().createQueue(queueName);

        setProducer(getSession().createProducer(jmsQueue));
        setQueueConnection(queueConnection);

        // Set Message "Time to Live" to the request timeout plus 10 minutes
        getProducer().setTimeToLive(getTimeout() + (10 * 60 * 1000L));
```

But nothing seems to work. I have the ActiveMQ-All jar in the Tomcat's lib folder and so too the jar where the GTCMessage class resides. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong? Is it a problem of a missing class or my bad configuration? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

The application is running on Tomcat 9, JAVA 1.8 and Active MQ 5.15.11.

Comment: Just to add, I am able to get the application to work with setTrustedPackages(true). But I dont want to leave the application "naked" so to speak!

Comment: Best options, don't use ObjectMessage, it was a horrible idea when they added it to the spec and it's a horrible idea now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're setting the name of the specific *class* rather than the *package* of the class. [The code](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/util/ClassLoadingAwareObjectInputStream.java#L100) looks at the package name, not the class name. Try this:

```java
// Set the trusted packages to move back and forth on the ActiveMQ JMS service.
ArrayList<String> trustedPackages = new ArrayList<String>();
trustedPackages.add("com.logicalprovisioning.common.gtc.shared");
ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = (ActiveMQConnectionFactory) environmentContext.lookup(queueConnectionFactoryNameLookup);
activeMQConnectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(trustedPackages);
```

I don't think you'll need to set this on the broker itself.

Aside from that I would strongly discourage you from using JMS `ObjectMessage`. They depend on Java serialization to marshal and unmarshal their object payload. This process is generally considered unsafe, because a malicious payload can exploit the host system. [Lots of CVEs](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=objectmessage) have been created for this which is why most JMS providers force users to explicitly whitelist packages that can be exchanged using `ObjectMessage` messages.

There are also a number of other issues with using JMS `ObjectMessage` not related to security that you should [read about](http://jmesnil.net/weblog/2012/07/27/on-jms-objectmessage-and-its-pitfalls/). This article has a good suggestion for how to replace `ObjectMessage` - define a data representation for the payload (JSON, protobuf, XML) and use `TextMessage` or `BytesMessage` to carry it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It was of great help!